# Room checks invalidations based on table modifications

Tags: android, android-room

> Note: Room checks invalidations based on table modifications, which means it may dispatch false positive notifications. [Guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide)

What is an invalidation for `Room`? How does it cause false positive notifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means,

Suppose you have below query

```
@Query(“SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userId = :id)
fun getUser(id: String): LiveData<User>
```

And you are observing it like

```
getUser("id_1").observe(this, Observer{
    // do something 
})
```

There is nothing wrong in above method, but there is the case of false positive notifications.

Now suppose that from somewhere else you have deleted user with an `userId = "id_2"`. At this point, you know that you don't need to get notified for your earlier `getUser("id_1")` call as it has nothing to do with your operations on `id_2`. But you still will get notified and your `// do something` will run again. That's because, Room will know that something has been changed, but doesn't know what has been changed and hence it will just re-query and send the result back again.

In order to bypass this false positive notification, you can use `MediatorLiveData` when you have `LiveData` as return type or `distinctUntilChanged` if you are have `RxJava` as return type in your Daos.

Ref: [7 Pro-tips for Room](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/7-pro-tips-for-room-fbadea4bfbd1)